# Unknown Script Gets Added in Footer

Tags: php, wordpress

The following script gets added in the footer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"beacon-4.newrelic.com","licenseKey":"07c6de90a5","applicationID":"2880104,2883430,2076767","transactionName":"ZFxQYhBUWkVTUkQKX10Wc1UWXFtYHUJZDVdfXA==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":80,"ttGuid":"","agentToken":"","userAttributes":"","errorBeacon":"jserror.newrelic.com","agent":"js-agent.newrelic.com\/nr-361.min.js"}</script>
```

I have disabled all plugins but its still there.

Its not present in footer.php, How to find out what's adding this code to the html source.

Comment: disabled plug-ins and delete that line?? What happen

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years, Allplugins are disabled and deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the URL in the code clearly says, this is code for the [New Relic](http://newrelic.com) performance monitor. It gets inserted automatically by a PHP/Apache module as long as it's active on your server.

Comment: So it is coming from my webhost, I m on GoDaddy managed WP ?

Comment: If *you* didn't install it, then yes, your host did. Check if you see anything related to New Relic in your GoDaddy control panel. If you do, I'd leave it there and use it (if GoDaddy provides you access to New Relic's data), it's a nice tool.